# C# process exception

Tags: c#

when running this code I get an exception

```
String cmd = "-redir:sim applu.res -max:inst {0} -pred {1} -assoc {2} -lvpt {3} -speedup {4} applu.ss<applu.in";

for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++) {
    cmd = cmd.Replace ("{" + i + "}", parameters [i]);
}
Console.WriteLine (cmd);

System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "./sim-spred";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.Start();    

Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

the sources are located in the debug folder

Comment: `"I get an exception"` is *insufficient information*. Please copy and paste the exact exception text. Also, if you run this in a debugger, it probably points you to the exact line. Include that information too.

Comment: Do you mind posting the exception?

Comment: Wheres the exception?

Comment: Also... why are you asking this question again? Please delete [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326195/c-sharp-capture-output-of-c-command-line-application-in-linux) if you are unhappy with how it turned out. You should focus on *asking good questions*, and not asking the same one over and over again!

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't told us where the exception is, I don't know if this is related to your problem or not. But,

This is why `String.Format` exists!

```
String cmd = "-redir:sim applu.res -max:inst {0} -pred {1} -assoc {2} -lvpt {3} -speedup {4} applu.ss<applu.in";

for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++) {
    cmd = cmd.Replace ("{" + i + "}", parameters [i]);
}
```

Try this instead:

```
var cmd = String.Format("-redir:sim applu.res -max:inst {0} -pred {1} -assoc {2} -lvpt {3} -speedup {4} applu.ss<applu.in",
    max_inst, pred, assoc, lvpt, speedup);
```